# Azure blob storage - Copy Block blobs in the SAME container

Tags: android, azure

I'm using Azure Storage with the Android API. I'm trying to copy one block blob from one location  to another (in the SAME blob container).

However, when I make the copy I get a "CannotVerifyCopySource" error after invoking the `startCopy` method.

Example Code:

```
private void sample(String path1, String path2, File file) {

    CloudBlockBlob blob1 = container.getBlockBlobReference(path1);
    CloudBlockBlob blob2 = container.getBlockBlobReference(path2);

    blob1.upload(new FileInputStream(file), file.length());
    blob1.startCopy(blob2);
}
```

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Best regards,

Comment: Looking at the error code details here about the error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179439.aspx, it seems blob service crapped out (500 Internal Server Error). Can you please capture more error details as suggested and share them here?

Comment: How do you know `blob1` is valid? Does the upload work? Does the upload complete before trying to do a copy from `blob1` to `blob2`?

Comment: The upload does complete (I used a breakpoint after the upload, checked the repository and the file was there, no exception thrown). All that code runs synchronously. The error is thrown in the startCopy method.

Answer (score 1):

see source about `startCopy` below. I think you should use `blob2.startCopy(blob1)` here.

```
/**
     * Requests the service to start copying a block blob's contents, properties, and metadata to a new block blob.
     *
     * @param sourceBlob
     *            A <code>CloudBlockBlob</code> object that represents the source blob to copy.
     *
     * @return A <code>String</code> which represents the copy ID associated with the copy operation.
     *
     * @throws StorageException
     *             If a storage service error occurred.
     * @throws URISyntaxException
     */
    @DoesServiceRequest
    public final String startCopy(final CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob) throws StorageException, URISyntaxException {
        return this.startCopy(sourceBlob, null /* sourceAccessCondition */,
                null /* destinationAccessCondition */, null /* options */, null /* opContext */);
    }
```